# Wordpress Search & Filter Autosubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm working with the Wordpress Search & Filter plugin and it's exactly what I needed for filtering though my gallery and shop content! I would like to make my selections submit every time a dropdown is changed, as opposed to having to click the submit button. (See link below).

In researching other posts, I've found that the solution is to implement this into my theme's java script file:

```
$(".searchandfilter select").change(function() {
$(".searchandfilter").submit();
});
```

I have put the line into my WooThemes Canvas's 'general.js' file but it seems to make no difference. I still need to click on the submit button to make changes. I've tried placing it in various other js files but I've had no luck. The page in questions is this one:

http://richardrosenman.com/wordpress/portfolio/

Does anyone have any insight as to what I'm doing wrong? I would REALLY appreciate any help as I'm stuck (and somewhat of a novice with Javascript!).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is loaded with `jQuery.noConflict();` therefore you cannot use `$` as selector (other libraries may be using it), instead use `jQuery` as selector:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".searchandfilter select").change(function() {
        jQuery(".searchandfilter").submit();
    });
});
```

I think you can add it to `general.js` end of file since I see that file is loaded.

Comment: Nice man, I was gonna add that it might need an on ready as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was already looking threw `general.js` for document.ready .. that file starts with it :). Modified. :)